# Определение количества пикселей определенного цвета на луче из центра координат

Tags: c#, изображения

Декартова система координат. Черно белое изображение. 
Центр находиться самостоятельно, основываясь на данных по общей площади изображения (центр тяжести).

Далее из центра нужно проводить лучи под углами от 0 до 360 с заданным шагом (например, 5 градусов). И для каждого луча, считать количество черных пикселей на нем.

Как пробовал считать я. Луч брал за гипотенузу, и через тангенс угла - находил противолежащий катет. Проделывал эту операцию для каждого пикселя по оси Х, и на пересечении координат пикселей Х и величины катета - проверял черный пиксель или нет.

Но данные какие то слишком неточные. Для изображения буквы "К" я получил почти одинаковые значения количества пикселей на всех лучах. Подозреваю, что я считаю не правильно. Делаю это на C# .NET.

Сама задача академическая. В чем суть. Строиться гистограмма, которая показывает отношение количества пикселей к углу луча. Для изображений символов, эти гистограммы субъективно похожи. Грубо говоря, для одного символа разных шрифтов - гистограммы будут схожи.

Координаты центра тяжести находятся по формулам.

Для координаты Х 
[image]

Для координаты Y
[image]

Функция A(). Значение равно 1 - если пиксель черный, 0 - если белый.

Посоветуйте что-то или подскажите решение.

Comment: - Если я правильно понимаю, единственный *корректный* способ — это провести честную растеризацию луча и проверять все полученные пиксели. См. [`Bresenham's line algorithm.`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm)

- Аналитически решать эту задачу нельзя, поскольку в зависимости от способа растеризации луча у вас могут получаться разные наборы пикселей на сетке, а ваш аналитический подход этого не учитывает.

Comment: - Лично на свой вкус я бы сгененировал бы для обрабатываемого изображения черно-белую маску, которая содержит все лучи (для этого даже не нужно реализовывать растеризацию, поскольку можно воспользоваться встроенными средствами языка), а после этого сделал бы попиксельный `AND` для двух изображений.

- Если нужно узнать количество совпавших пикселей **на каждом луче** в отдельности, но можно применить этот же подход, но с генерацией отдельных масок для каждого луча.

Comment: @Котик: а не будет ли количество пикселей просто равно модулю разности абсцисс или ординат в начальной и конечной точке, в зависимости от того, что больше? Для Брезенхэма это, кажется, верно.

Comment: @VladD

- Да, для Брезенхэма это верно. Только (допускаю, что я мог неправильно понять, какую задачу ставит автор) это знание никак нам не помогает.

- Автор хочет для какого-то исходного изображения (например, буквы "K") нарисовать лучи из найденного центра тяжести и найти сумму всех пикселей *в изображении этой самой буквы "K",* на которые попали проведенные лучи.

- Соответственно, знание того, сколько пикселей получилось на каждом луче в результате работы Брезенхэма никак не помогает в ответе на этот вопрос.

Comment: Глобальную задачу сейчас добавлю в вопрос.

Comment: @Котик: ах да, и правда не помогает, я не дочитал задачу. Тем не менее, ждём глобальной постановки проблемы.

Comment: Обновил пост.

Comment: @Jakeroid В общем, я бы на вашем месте сделал все это способом, который я предложил во втором своем комментарии (с отдельными масками на каждый луч). Выглядит дешево и сердито.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите картинку

[image]

Ваши лучи наложенные на пиксельную сетку дают большую погрешность.
Судя по всему, дело именно в этом.

Вот еще хорошая картинка, на которой видно что как лучи пересекают пиксели.
[image]

Comment: А может существует другой способ просчета точек луча? Может я сильно грубо считаю?

Comment: смотря как трактовать выражение "пиксель лежит на луче". поясните.

Comment: Грубо говоря, мне нужно двигаться вдоль луча. Как на вашей второй картинке. И считать количество черных пикселей до конца изображения. Или другими словами, нужно посчитать, сколько пикселей, через которые проходит луч - черные.

Comment: ну я бы делал так
1) определил бы клетки (пиксели), которые пересекает луч.
2) из всех пересеченных клеток выбрал бы черные и посчитал их количество.

Пункт 1 требует четкого понимания что считать пересеченой клеткой. Например, самый левая нижняя клетка на рис 2, которую все лучи "пересекают" лишь "вскользь" "с боку". Считать ее пересеченой или нет?
И еще важный момент. Откуда выходят лучи? Из центра клетки (0,0) или из ее угла (как на рисунке 2)?

Comment: Лучи выходят из центра клетки. А каким образом тогда считать пересекает луч клетку или нет? У меня вообще в голове не укладывается.